# Javascript weird comparison result

Tags: javascript

I have two strings declared in Javascript as follows:

```
var str1 = new String('Hello');
var str2 = 'Hello';
```

Comparison results:

```
str1 == str2 // true
str1 === str2 // false
```

My questions is, why is `===` yields to **false** when both strings are equal in value and have the same `string` type?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're comparing a String **object** with a **primitive** string. Those are two different types.

To make it clearer, here are [all JS types](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Data_structures):

> - Six data types that are primitives:
>
>   - Boolean
>   - Null
>   - Undefined
>   - Number
>   - String
>   - Symbol (new in ECMAScript 6)
> - and Object

When compared using `===`, an object is only equal to itself (and thus not to a primitive value nor to another identical object)

When comparing using `==`, EcmaScript follows [this procedure](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/9.0/index.html#sec-abstract-equality-comparison), which calls the `toString` method on the String object.

There's normally no reason to explicitly use String objects (you implicitly use them every time your code needs an object and you pass a string, but the JS engine handles the promotion for you). You should almost always stick to primitive strings.

Answer (score 2):

Because

```
typeof new String('Hello') === 'object'
```

and

```
typeof 'Hello' === 'string'
```

The former is an object, the latter is a primitive.

The `==` check works because the `String` object has also `toString` method and JS invokes that method in this case (as well as when concatenating with other string).

Comment: I would like to add the caveat that `var a = new String("Hello")` and `var b = new String("Hello")` are also not `===`, i.e. `a === b //returns false`

Comment: @Mortz Of course because each object instance has it's own pointer/memory address. Just like `{} === {}` give false

Comment: Yes. I just wanted to point it out to the OP (and not add a separate answer to point this) that just because two objects have the same "value" doesn't mean they are the "same" :)

Answer (score 0):

A string object is not a primitive string and therefore will not be equal completely by using `===`. 
Instead, if you insist on using `===` you can use the `valueOf` function, like:

```
new String("hello").valueOf() === str2
```